# Power shell does not recognize ssh

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, openssh

ssh does not work from powershell but working fine with cmd
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxnTY.png)

I've checked environment path seems OK
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzblh.png)

any idea what might be wrong ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [su].

Comment: In the same console, what is your output from `$env:path -split ";"` ? Does it contain the OpenSSH path?

Comment: Yes, It contains C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for regedit in the Run app in windows and follow this route in the picture:

[image]

Add the selected value and it should work , it's a permission issue.

Comment: Please don't share code in pictures, copy the registry address and the value of the key into the answer text so that other people don't need to retype them.